# Deployment keeps failing without output

Tags: node.js, github, heroku, discord.js

Since 3pm, I can't deploy my app from Github.
I can't access build log either : "Unable to display build output"

I don't know where the problem might be since everything was fine before 3pm and even reverting to previous version doesn't solution the problem.

Comment: I am getting this also, although there is a github status, it seems to indicate it should be fixed, and the heroku deployment is showing it is able to fetch the github code... It just started working now (after about 10+ retries)

Comment: github has issue..

Comment: Running into the same issue

Comment: My most recent build just passed. Try and rebuild now, the github issues seem to have resolved.